# Why does HttpServlet throw an IOException?

Tags: java, servlets

I get why an HttpServlet would throw ServletException, but why IOException?  What was the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> IOException - if an input or output error is detected when the servlet handles the GET request

This can happen when you print the servlet output:

response.getWriter().print()  - this method throws IOException

The socket can be closed before the response finishes to print the output.

Comment: Actually, calling `print()` _doesn't_ throw an IOException (that's a gotcha!). If you call `getOutputStream()` rather than `getWriter()`, you'll have IOExceptions, but the PrintWriter swallows all write exceptions. You have to manually call `checkError()` after your writes to find out if something went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that an `IOException` indicates a problem with processing input/output, e.g. problems reading from the request input, or writing the response, whereas a `ServletException` has more to do with servlet-specific problems, such as errors regarding servlet provisioning/initialisation, and processing requests.

Answer (score 0):

If the servlet writes to an output stream (i.e. the page) through I/O interfaces, any I/O error will be reported as an `IOException`.

Perhaps the API shouldn't be using I/O interfaces directly. It's not uncommon for WebApps using RMI to allow the `RMIException` to be fall through the servlet interface (it's a subclass of `IOException` for some reason).